# Getting casting error on config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I am trying to use dependency injection in my web api project through unity container but I am getting compile time exception

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'APIIntegrationApp.UnityResolver' to 'System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I am referring to this link for my implementation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IMFOCustomerRepository, MFOCustomerRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

Here's my IDependencyResolver interface and unityresolver class definitions

```
public interface IDependencyResolver : IDependencyScope, IDisposable
{
    IDependencyScope BeginScope();
}

public interface IDependencyScope : IDisposable
{
    object GetService(Type serviceType);
    IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType);
}

 public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    protected IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch (ResolutionFailedException)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
        return new UnityResolver(child);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the first 27 lines of your `UnityResolver` class.

Comment: I have shared the class definition

Comment: The issue is that you have written your own `IDependencyResolver` and `IDependencyScope` interfaces. You shouldn't do that. You should remove those two. Those two interfaces are **built in** - hence why your error message says `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver`.

Comment: Even after removing those two interfaces and from unit container class I am still getting the same cast error

Comment: `public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver`. Right click on `IDependencyResolver` and click `Go To Definition`. What interface does it take you to? In what namespace?

Comment: To be clear, `UnityResolver` **must** implement `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver`.

Answer (score -1):

This error is typically thrown because there's either a type mismatch (think `int myInt = 'some string'`) or a particular class doesn't inherit from an interface that's being expected. The below example shows this:

```
public interface IClassA
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class ClassA
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something here
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IClassA obj = new ClassA(); // throws error because ClassA doesn't inherit from IClassA
    }
}
```

The solution to this issue would simply be inheriting the needed interface(s) which is common in dependency injection.